# React Testing: Storing Enzyme's find() output in a variable for DRYness

Tags: jestjs, enzyme

I'm using Jest and Enzyme to test a React component. Sometimes I find myself typing the same thing over and over using `find()`, so I attempted to DRY up my code as follows:

**Repetitive Code**

```
component.setProps({ something: 'hello' });
expect(component.find('SomeField').prop('disabled')).toBe(false);

component.setProps({ something: 'good' });
expect(component.find('SomeField').prop('disabled')).toBe(true);

component.setProps({ something: 'abc' });
expect(component.find('SomeField').prop('disabled')).toBe(false);
```

**Attempt at DRY**

```
const someField = component.find('SomeField');

component.setProps({ something: 'hello' });
expect(someField.prop('disabled')).toBe(false);

component.setProps({ something: 'good' });
expect(someField.prop('disabled')).toBe(true);

component.setProps({ something: 'abc' });
expect(someField.prop('disabled')).toBe(false);
```

*Given that:*

```
component = shallow(<MyComponent />);
```

However that approach doesn't work. Can someone explain why? Furthermore, it would be nice if anyone could suggest a way to drying that up, if that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is: What happens on `setProps`? Its the same what happens in your react component in the browser, every time the props changes, the render function is called. With `const someField = component.find('SomeField');` you store one of the rendered child components, but calling `setProps` after this, will force the component to render new child components. So the stored one is not the one that your component change something on.

I would suggest to just leave the non dry function as it is to leave the test as simple as possible.